# difficulties solving recursive integrals with sage

Tags: python, symbolic-math, sage

I have recently asked a question on math.stackexchange concerning how to compute [volumes of intersecting hypercubes and hyperspheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996000/intersection-of-hypercube-and-hypersphere/) to which I got an extremely helpful answer.

Now, I'm trying to utilize `sage` to generate some analytic solution for the lowest dimensionalities. With my very naive understanding of sage, the help of google and some trial & error, I came up with the following solution:

```
from sage.symbolic.integration.integral import definite_integral

R = var("R")
assume(R>0)
x = var("x")

V0(R) = 1
V = [V0]

for i in range(1,4):
    vlast = V[i-1]
    vnew(R) = definite_integral( vlast(R=sqrt(R**2 - x**2)),x,-min(R,1),min(R,1))
    V.append(vnew)        

print(V)
```

However, the output is not quite what I expected:

```
[R |--> 1, R |--> 2*R, R |--> pi*R^2, R |--> 4/3*pi*R^3]
```

Sage calculates the volumes of the n-dimesional spheres very nicely, but it somehow doesn't pick up the fact that the resulting function will be defined piecewise in R.

Is there something wrong about how I use the `min` function? Is there something wrong with how I define (or name) my variables? Where am I messing up?

Comment: Maybe use `min_symbolic`.

Comment: That is already very helpful, but now sage seems unable to perform the integration:`[R |--> 1, R |--> 2*min(1, R), R |--> 2*integrate(min(1, sqrt(R^2 - x^2)), x, -min(1, R), min(1, R))]`. I already tried installing and using `fricas` to proceed, but now I get this: `Cannot find a definition
or applicable library operation named min with argument type(s)
Variable(R) PositiveInteger` - any further suggestions?